# Incremental parsing using ANTLR4

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, antlr4

We use ANTLR4(in c#) in custom IDE to parse object-oriented language. Results from parser help us create some set of features (code highlighting, code assistance, region outlining etc.). But for future improvements of usability we need to make working ANTLR4 incrementally. For example if user type some code in method body, we don't want to reparse all file (because it can be very large), we want reparse only block that affected after user typing. Good example of incremental parsing is [Papa_Carlo](http://lakhin.com/projects/papa-carlo/), but it use PEG grammars to generate parser. We want to use ANTLR for this.

Is there any way to do this? It's possible?

Comment: The answer is almost no. That requires fundamental changes.